# How to delete duplicate rows in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I ran an SQL code that goes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Track, Artist, Valence, Stream
FROM dbo.[spotify _db]
ORDER BY Stream DESC, Valence DESC
```

This resulted to:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXCdu.png)

The desired output should be

| - | - | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blinding Lights | The Weeknd | 0.334 | 3386520288 |
| Shape of You | Ed Sheeran | 0.931 | 336200520 |
| Someone You Loved | Lewis Capaldi | 0.446 | 2634013335 |
| rockstar (feat.... | Post Malone | 0.129 | 2594926619 |
| Sunflower .... | Post Malone | 0.925 | 2538329799 |
| One Dance | Drake | 0.37 | 2522431995 |
| Closer | The Chainsmokers | 0.661 | 2456205158 |

*Notice that Sunflower and Closer should be one track name*

I tried using DISTINCT so that the duplicate song titles (because they are of the same artist) will not show but it keeps on showing. Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Who wins?  Swae Lee or Post Malone?

Comment: Always best to post sample data and desired results as text

Comment: Please do not paste images of code or data please paste text

Comment: I attached the screenshot of how SQL showed the result and how I wanted the result to be. I can't seem to code the table based on Github instructions.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support Also please show your input data, and please explain the logic desired. Why are some artists shown and not others?

Comment: Does this help you? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: I tried the one with TOP 1 WITH TIES solution and it removed the duplicate track names but it did not arrange it according to the track with the highest stream. Is there something else that I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed something, this is the code. You can only change the priority based on the type of sorting

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tRACK ORDER BY Stream DESC, Valence DESC) RW
     FROM SONG
)A
WHERE A.RW=1
ORDER BY Stream DESC
```

Comment: Yes, this one also worked. I just added ORDER BY Stream DESC after the WHERE Statement. Thank you for your help!

Comment: your welcome. I edited the code based on your request